# List the folders name inside s3 bucket using aws-sdk in React project

Tags: reactjs, aws-sdk-nodejs

I am creating a ui in react to list folders inside s3 bucket and when I click on specific folder, I will see the list of objects present in that folder.

Currently, I am able to get the list of all objects inside s3 bucket using `listsObjectsV2` method of aws-sdk. But first I want to get the list of folder in that bucket.

Below is the code:

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import AWS from 'aws-sdk';

const Home = () => {
    AWS.config.update({
      accessKeyId: 'keyId',
      secretAccessKey: 'accessKey',
      s3Url: 'url'
    });
    
    const s3 = new AWS.S3();

    const params = {
      Bucket: 'bucket name',
      Delimiter: '',
      Prefix: ''`your text`
    };

  const [listFiles, setListFiles] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    s3.listObjectsV2(params, (err, data) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err, err.stack);
      } else {
        setListFiles(data.Contents);
        console.log(data.Contents);
      }
    });
  }, [])


  return (
    <>
      <ul>
        {listFiles &&
          listFiles.map((name, index) => (
            <li key={index}>
              {name.Key}
            </li>
          ))}
     </ul>
    </>
  )
}

export default Home
```

Comment: You shouldn't be putting your secret key in your front end code. People will be able to see it then use it for nefarious purposes. Also are the folders empty? I think S3 doesn't actually have folders, all the files are just  flatly stored in one place but their UI creates folders based on the slashed path name

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I was about to put them in a .env file. The folders are not empty. I can get the objects prefixed with the folder names and "/". So, I have to take care of the part before "/" in my UI to get the objects inside the specific folders and can use prefix="folderName/" to get the objects.

Comment: Doesn't matter if you put your credentials in the code or in an env file. They will end up in your frontend code running in the user's browser. That's a big NOGO.